# How to navigate through all highlighted texts in the DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, filter, highlight

I have a pipe that highlights a text passed through an input field, it works fine.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'highlighter',
})
export class HighlighterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, args: string): unknown {
    if (!args) {
      return value;
    }

    const re = new RegExp(args, 'ig');
    value = value.replace(re, '<span class="highlighted-text">$&</span>');
    
    return value;
}
```

Now, the next step is basically navigate throught all of them by using a next and previous button, just like this:

[image]

So, whenever the user hits the next or previous button, it will cause a scrolling behavior to the text highlighted, it does not necessarily need to be a smooth scroll, it's not relevant for now, but just get into the target one.

I had a basic idea of how to implement it by adding IDs to the list of highlighted texts, and somehow matching them. However, the problem is that I'm experiencing the change event on this input search, so I think it could be more difficult if I add and remove the ID attribute over and over again while the user is writing something down, not to mention the performance itself.

Any idea would be appreciated!
Thank you!